# Why is the for loop only performed once?

Tags: python-3.x

I tried to delete the val value in nums.

```
nums=[3,3]  
val=3

class Solution:
    def removeElement(self, nums, val):
        if not nums:
            return []
        for i in nums:
            if i == val:
                nums.remove(i)
        return nums
```

**I excepted: `[]`**

**but Output: `[3]`**

Maybe this is a stupid question.But I hope someone can help me explain it. Thank you.

Comment: what is your input?

Comment: Don't remove from a list while iterating the same list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove items from a list while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Comment: Also, unrelated, by why do you return `0` if `nums` is `[]`?

Comment: @tobias. Not really a dupe since the other question is asking how, this one why.

Comment: @MadPhysicist That was just the first (somewhat) dupe that I found, but there must be about thirty more, possibly better fitting ones.

Comment: @tobias_k. That is definitely true.

Comment: @tobias_k  my bad. it's []

Comment: Well, mere returning the list doesn't really change the main `num` list, you've gotta reassign the `num` variable to that output.

Comment: @UbdusSamad. Not true. In OP's version, modification is done in place, which is why most of the answers are only telling half the story. Having a method with no returns is acutally a great use-case for doing this sort of filtering.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, Sorry I blindly ignored the `list.remove()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great example of why you should not modify a list while you iterate over it. List is somewhat unusual because it actually allows you to do the modification in a fairly predictable manner. Many other iterable objects will raise an error if you even try.

When you do `for i in nums`, it is converted to `for i in iter(nums)`. The iterator over a list keeps track of the index that you are at. Here is what happens in your loop:

1. `nums` is `[3, 3]`, the iterator is at position zero:

   ```
   3, 3
   ^
   ```
2. The item matches `val`, so it is removed. The list is shifted back one item:

   ```
   3
   ^
   ```
3. The iterator moves forward one item. This is the end of the list, so iteration stops:

   ```
   3
     ^
   ```

This will happen whenever you have any pair of matching elements sequentially within the list. It would not happen if your list was `[3, 4, 3]`:

1. Start

   ```
   3, 4, 3
   ^
   ```
2. Remove

   ```
   4, 3
   ^
   ```
3. Increment

   ```
   4, 3
      ^
   ```
4. Remove

   ```
   4
      ^
   ```
5. End

There are a couple of ways of getting the filtered list. The most obvious, that is hashed to death in the other answers, is to make a new list, usually via comprehension:

```
nums = [x for x in nums if x != val]
```

There is, however, an in-place solution as well. It is not really optimal, but for cases where you *must* work in place, it is a possibility. You can always implement your own iteration steps if you iterate over the index intelligently:

```
i = 0
while i < len(nums):  # Note that len is called in every iteration
    if nums[i] == val:
        nums.remove[i]
    else:
        i += 1
```

Something like this is a good idea if your method can not return the list for some reason.

As an afterthought, you can even do in-place filtering with a comprehension:

```
nums[:] = [x for x in nums if x != val]
```

This creates a temporary list, and assigns its *contents* to the *contents* of `nums`, but does not change the object `nums` refers to.

Comment: Thank you.That's a great explanation.

Comment: @D.T, Glad it helped. I added one more workaround at the end

Comment: Why nums[:], not nums?

Comment: @D.T `nums = ...` assigns a new object to `nums` you will never see the change outside your function if you do not return this new reference. `nums[:] = ...` replaces the elements of the current object, without creating a new reference. The second version is in-place: it modifies the original input list so that the change is visible outside your function.

Answer (score 0):

Never delete (or alter) the list while iterating over it.

Comprehension is going to solve your problems:

```
nums = [i for i in nums if i != val]
```

**What happened in your case?**

1. You went through list.
2. First element was `3`
3. You removed it.
4. Second element became the first.
5. You were already checking the first element so now it is skipped.
6. Loop ends.
7. You are left with `[3]`.

Comment: "Never delete (or alter) the list while iterating over it." Why such an absolute? If you do it sensibly, it may not be a good idea, but I can think of where it is a perfectly valid solution.

Comment: It does sound Sith but sometimes it's for the best :)

Comment: One example of where OP's code is useful is when you need to modify the list in-place. Your solution does not allow this directly.

Answer (score 0):

As @tobias_k has said in comments, it's a bad idea to remove items from a list while you're iterating over that list. Instead, you should keep track of another list of items not equal to the parameter `val`.

```
def removeElement(self, nums, val):
    if not nums:
        return []
    remaining = []
    for num in nums:
        if num != val:
            remaining.append(num)
    return remaining
```

For your purpose, what I have above is logically equivalent to the other answers.

Comment: This has one crucial difference from OP's solution: it is not in-place.

Answer (score 0):

Removing items from a list when you're iterating through the list causes problems because you're causing the list to shift around at the same time that the loop is trying to keep track of its position.

Suppose you have a list of Fruits: Apple, Banana, Banana, Cherry, Date. Suppose you want to remove Banana. So you write code to do this:

```
for each fruit in Fruits
    if fruit is Banana
        remove fruit
```

Here's one possible scenario, depending on how iteration is implemented by the programming language or library: First, the code points to element 0 (assuming zero-based indexing), where it finds Apple. Apple doesn't match Banana. So the code moves on to the next item in the list, in position 1: Banana. Banana matches Banana, so that Banana is removed.

Now the list Fruits consists of Apple, Banana, Cherry, Date. The second Banana is sitting at position 1, where the first Banana had been. The Cherry is now sitting where the second Banana had been, in position 2; and the Date is sitting where Cherry had been, in position 3.

Since the code has *already* done a comparison and deletion at position 1, it isn't going to do another one! It's time for it to increment, to move on to position 2, where it finds Cherry. This means that it has skipped over the second Banana. When the loop completes, you'll still have that second Banana there. The list will be Apple, Banana, Cherry, Date.

An approach that *may* work, depending on how arrays are implemented (including whether they are dynamic and you can remove elements from them without causing the remaining elements to be resequenced), is to create an array from the elements in the list, and then iterate through them by index, in turn, from n-1 through 0 (assuming zero-based arrays). You have to do it in reverse order or else you'll run into the same problem as before. When you iterate in reverse order, a deletion causes the elements *you've already visited* to shift, but not the elements you haven't visited yet.

Answer (score -1):

```
for i in nums:
    if i == val:
        nums.remove(i)
```

The issue is that you are iterating through a list while you are changing it. A quicker way to do this without editing the original list is using list comprehension:

```
if not nums:
    return 0
return (x for x in nums if x != val)
```

Comment: This returns a generator, not a list. Also, it is not an in-place solution. This is not really equivalent to OP's code.

Answer (score -1):

I don't work in python, but from what I see, you're trying to remove 1 element from an array. If you know the element, why not simply try:
- do not loop
- try to remove the 1 element from numns
- use exception handling if needed ie element might not exist in array
- return nums

you could also try exiting the loop once the element is found. No need to go further if you removed the element you want to remove.

Comment: I don't think you understood the question at all.

Comment: That was a very helpful comment thank you :)

Seems to me: if i == val:  nums.remove(i)
would be the same as nums.remove(val)

Comment: "you're trying to remove 1 element from an array". No, that is not what OP is doing. OP is trying to remove all matching elements from the array, which is all of the elements in this particular case, and wondering why some are still left.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the vague comment.